# How could I remove rows in a SQL query with same value if a certain variable searched was not found?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So I'm trying to build a refine search function.

```
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| attr_id | part          | var   | value     |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 17      | CAT1125P      | color | Black     |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 1       | CAT1125P      | make  | Chevy     |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 2       | CAT1125P      | model | Silverado |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 3       | CAT1125P      | year  | 2012      |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 25      | CAT1125P      | year  | 2011      |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 19      | BDS10-6347-SE | make  | Chevy     |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 21      | BDS10-6347-SE | make  | Toyota    |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 24      | BDS10-6347-SE | model | Yukon     |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 18      | BDS10-6347-SE | year  | 2011      |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
| 26      | BDS10-6347-SE | year  | 2010      |
+---------+---------------+-------+-----------+
```

Above is the Attributes table (attr for short). The admin can add any kind of Variable (var) and value. I'm trying to make the query run something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `attr` WHERE EXISTS 
    (SELECT * FROM `attr` WHERE var="year" AND value="2010") 
AND var NOT IN('year')

UNION

SELECT * FROM `attr` WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM `attr` WHERE var="year" AND value="2010") 
AND value="2010";
```

Here's the SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63bb7c/1

The problem with the above code is even if it cant find '2010' for CAT1125P, it will still query for other variables. Is there any way I could exclude that part if the other values don't pertain to the variable being searched? (year 2010 was not found for CAT1125P so exclude that part from results) I tried doing that in the WHERE EXISTS statement, but I just can't wrap my head around this one.

And for multiple variables, there shouldn't be any results for the following query. I'm looking for a product that's year 2010 and model Silverado: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/63bb7c/2

Comment: MySQL. SQL Server. Pick one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're determined to stick with your eav model then you could consider something like this...

```
SELECT part
     , MAX(CASE WHEN var = 'make' THEN value END) make
     , MAX(CASE WHEN var = 'model' THEN value END) model
     , MAX(CASE WHEN var = 'year' THEN value END) year
  FROM attr
 GROUP
    BY part;
```

By coincidence, the result set is identical in appearance to a properly normalized structure!

Answer (score -1):

I think that your are modeling this incorrectly. If your goal is to be able to query parts for a 2011 Chevy Silverado, then you should denormalize this into a parts table, a make table a model table and a year table and then add foreign key relationships among them all.

Right now you could query a 2011 Chevy Yukon or a 2011 Toyota Yukon, neither of which I believe are real cars since GMC makes the Yukon...I am not sure if they are owned by Chevy or not, but none the less, it is definitely not a Toyota.

Having said all that, if the goal is that you want to get the list of parts that are valid for a 2010 Silverado, then do something like this

```
SELECT part FROM attr 
  WHERE part IN (SELECT part FROM attr WHERE var = 'year' AND value = '2010') 
  AND var = 'model' AND value = 'Silverado'
```

And to show it retrieving a valid part for a 2012 Silverado

```
SELECT part FROM attr 
  WHERE part IN (SELECT part FROM attr WHERE var = 'year' AND value = '2012') 
  AND var = 'model' AND value = 'Silverado'
```

And with all three variables

```
SELECT part FROM attr 
  WHERE part IN (SELECT part FROM attr WHERE var = 'year' AND value = '2012') 
    AND part IN (SELECT part FROM attr WHERE var = 'make' AND value = 'Chevy') 
    AND var = 'model' AND value = 'Silverado'
```

Comment: Just add another subquery

Comment: @zethw See JOIN. Subqueries are not the answer to everything. +1 for advice on normalization tho